# Does the EFF mod still work with Skyrim Special Edition?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I installed the [Extensible Follower Framework](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/12933/), now Skyrim simply doesn't load, It just quits. Is there a log file or something where I can see what's wrong?

Does the mod still work with Skyrim Special Edition?

[image: Skyrim Mod Manager]

It seems that I have no other plugin. Even removing the Dibella plugin will still cause problems.

Comment: It hasn't been updated since April 2016, which was months before Skyrim SE came out. Weren't most mods in need of rework to be compatible with the SE version?

Comment: Skyrim SE broke numerous mods, especially ones that require Skyrim Script Extender (SKSE). Until SKSE is updated, those mods will not be updated.

Comment: I got it. Can you turn that into an answer? I am using mod for skyrim special edition now. Ot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EFF won't work on `Skyrim Special Edition` as it requires `SKSE`. Even when `SKSE` get a release for `Skyrim SE`, there is no way to know if EFF can work out of the box.